# iPad Split View Master not in split mode but as popup

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad

In principle I want to implement a split view. 
But I need the master to pop up not only in portrait orientation but in landscape orientation as well. Consequentally I do not want the view to be split at all in landscape orientation.

What is a proper way to implement that? 
Is is smart using a split view at all or would you guys suggest an alternative approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in iOS 5 using the [`UISplitViewControllerDelegate`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UISplitViewControllerDelegate_protocol/Reference/Reference.html) method `splitViewController:shouldHideViewController:inOrientation:`.

```
- (BOOL)splitViewController:(UISplitViewController *)svc shouldHideViewController:(UIViewController *)vc inOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)orientation
{
    return (vc == myMasterViewController);
}
```

If you need to support iOS 4 then you will need to create a custom split view controller or use something like [MGSplitViewController](https://github.com/mattgemmell/MGSplitViewController).

However, I would *only* do this if you are going to in fact show two view controllers split on the screen at once. This, really, is the main purpose of a split view controller. It sounds like you might not really need a split view controller, so I would consider just handling the popover yourself by presenting a `UIPopoverController` of your master view controller from a button on your navigation bar. Then you can just use a standard `UINavigationController` as your root view controller.

Comment: Thanks, that was quick. Yes I do need iOS4 support. Both of you were right but your answer was more detailed, providing options.

Answer (score 1):

`MGSplitViewController` will allow you to do this:

https://github.com/mattgemmell/MGSplitViewController